# Ways to measure memcached installation before and after?

Tags: php, performance, memcached

What are some options to measure performance before installing memcached and then after you have installed it?

I don't want to install it and then and build it into my code unless I have a way of measuring what I'm implementing.  I'll be using the php client if that makes a difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to profile PHP code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133686/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-php-code)

Comment: That will only measure php performance itself won't it?  Not the affect of the memcached installation.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not sure where you are expecting the difference to be? You profile your app; install memcached; profile it again. I don't think there is anything more specific than that

Comment: Thanks Pekka.  I'll get onto it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I guess you want to measure the performance of an application as it is now and after you include memcached in the stack?

The way I'd approach this is run some tests i.e. measure how part of your application performance e.g. how long does a page take to generate, preferably with real user behaviour, add memcached and re-run the tests.

One of the things to monitor during the tests is what's you cache hit ratio like i.e. how much is coming from memcached rather than the DB.

Other thing to remember in memcached works well in read heavy applications.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I would have preferred some more detail on what programs are out there to accomplish this, but in the end I went with Siege and the built in profiler that comes with Codeigniter.  It seemed to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Memcached stores some of your sql queries. In the documenation there is a chapter how to test your installation. I think you can just telnet to your server and type some strange commands.