# Wordpress website waits 7 secs to send more HTTP requests

Tags: php, html, wordpress, http, themes

I'm building a website using a Wordpress theme The Travel Theme (http://thetraveltheme.com/). The problem is that the website is loading really slowly. Let me explain - after the initial HTTP request, it takes seven seconds to send other requests. See the picture.
[image: Network activity]

Since it happens on my website as well as on the official theme website using this theme, it's most likely theme-related problem. It shouldn't be caused by plugins. I was thinking maybe it tries to connect somewhere and the connection times out after seven seconds, but I can't figure out more.

I [contacted](http://thetraveltheme.proboards.com/index.cgi?board=general&action=display&thread=166#1337407774) the theme developers, but no reply so far.

Do you have any idea what might cause it and where to look for a problem?

Comment: have you tried changing themes and seeing if the problem still occurs? This sounds like a webserver problem rather than a problem with WordPress

Comment: Have you tried it with another theme?

Comment: So it took the server 6.6s to send the rendered html after the initial request.. so you've identified the bottleneck as Apache or one of its modules(php). [Profile your PHP and go from there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133686/profiling-php-code)

Comment: It is likely because of all the scripts it is loading in the header.php. Try loading jquery from your local folder for one. Also loading cufon fonts will slow down your loading time.

Comment: Thank you all for tips. With other themes, the website starts loading within hundreds of miliseconds. It must be theme-related.
I tried to move javascript to load from footer instead of header, but it didn't help significantly.

Comment: Try adding [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by Simon [here](http://thetraveltheme.proboards.com/index.cgi?action=display&board=general&thread=166&page=1#592).

„There are external calls to a webserver in Australia to fetch these advertisment urls and these calls block the whole theme.
So if you want a quick and dirty solution to avoid these delays just comment the codeblock in the `footer.php` file in the root of the theme.
Everything in the `div` element `footer_bottom` but not this part in the beginning:

```
<div id="copyright"><?php echo wpml_t(THEME_NAME, 'Copyright Footer Text',stripslashes(theme_get_option('footer','copyright')));            
wp_reset_query();
```

This should give an performance boost +90% for the inital connect and +60% for the complete site (depending on different factors). Of course there are many other ways to improve the performance but this one should make the situation acceptable for the moment.“ (Simon)

I hope this helps other guys using The Travel Theme.

Comment: OOps! Forum deleted for violation of t&c's. Sounds like an alround dodgy theme.