# My script to deliver emails based on each user's local time

Tags: php, mysql, email, codeigniter, time

I'm posting my php script hoping for your opinions and advice. My PHP application needs to send individual emails to users based on their local time.

Each user has a set of time-marks at which they chose to receive emails. This is how a time-marks field looks like in the database: `12:00:00, 14:15:00, 16:30:00`.

I'm rounding time-marks to the nearest quarter hour and sending cronjobs every quarter hour to check which users are scheduled for an email and sending respective emails **one-by-one** (worried look :-/) in a loop.

My server timezone is set to `America/New_York` so I can't send emails based on my time because users are in different locations. Below I developed a model that should handle the issue.

**Solution:**

1. Collect each user's timezone
2. On each cronjob get each user's localtime in php using their timezone
   data
3. Create array of user's time-marks.

   Example: `12:00:00, 14:15:00, 16:30:00` to

   `Array ( [0] => 12:00:00 [1] => 14:15:00 [2] => 16:30:00 )`
4. If user's localtime matches one of his/her time-mark send email
5. Update database with date sent

**Php script:**

```
    //loop through user's entries table that holds content to be emailed    
    foreach ($entries as $entry) { 

         //create array of user's time-marks set            
         $timemarks_arr = array_map( "trim", str_getcsv($entry->timemarks));

         //get user's localtime
         $timezone = $entry->timezone; //user's time-zone
         $userlocaltime = gmt_to_local($timestamp, $timezone, $daylight_saving); //gets user's localtime

         //if a user's time-mark matches his/her localtime      
         if (in_array($userlocaltime, $timemarks_arr))
         {  
                //send email using Codeigniter's email class

                $this->email->clear(); //reset between cycles

                $this->email->from('myemail@gmail.com', 'Name');
                $this->email->to($entry->email); 

                $this->email->subject($entry->content);
                $this->email->message($entry->content); 

                $this->email->send();   

                echo $this->email->print_debugger();                    

                //update date sent
                $user_id = $entry->user_id;

                $this->db->query("UPDATE `entries` SET date_sent=now() WHERE `user_id` = $user_id AND `entry_id` = $entry->entry_id");

         }

    }
```

**Concerns:**

- Is the model reliable?
- Performance issues. It takes about 5 seconds to send just 4 emails.. (note: I'm sending emails from testing environment on my local windows server - WAMP)

Comment: Maybe it's taking long because your sending `UPDATE` queries in every loop iteration.  It might be better to just build an array of `user_id` and `entry_id`'s that were sent, then create one SQL command after the loop has completed.

Comment: @MrSlayer, it takes that long without the update query as well

Comment: Performance Issues: First step is to [profile your code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133686/profiling-php-code)

Comment: @MikeB, thanks. Based on profiling data it takes `2.1155` seconds to send 1 email.. I suppose stmp is to blame?

Comment: why not convert each users prefered timestamp to its corresponding time in your timezone before saving it rather than store it and have to convert it for each calculation?

Comment: @JohnB that's a great idea! I haven't considered it

Comment: ya, not having to do all those calculations should save you a bunch of time

Comment: @JohnB, the only issue I can think of using that method is daylight savings. Doing the calculations always gives the current correct time whereas saved timestamp records might be outdated.

Comment: you could always store a daylight savings and non daylight saving time then and just change up which field youre searching depending on whether or not its daylight savings.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12134/discussion-between-cyberjunkie-and-john-b)

Answer (score 0):

unless you set up a server script for server time all you can do is get local time.

What i would do is write a simple program in c++, or some other language that can update your database records. Have the program set up to record the server time into the database by the hour, and when users need to call to it have them read that field from the database. I have done this before and it worked pretty well.