# Header redirect taking a long time

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

I have two servers running the exact code, while the staging server works like a charm the production server is extremely slow when it comes to redirecting.

1. [Working Link](http://staging.hemisphereinteractive.com/vidid/facebook.php?id=pZBk3c9DRNvWQcg7Ls4Q8V5CC9ugM9Bj&fid=4AAdR_VnE9f2)
2. [Link with long response delay](http://player.boomvideo.tv/facebook.php?id=pZBk3c9DRNvWQcg7Ls4Q8V5CC9ugM9Bj&fid=4AAdR_VnE9f2)

I've searched through google and used a few of there alternatives but nothing seems to do the trick.

Current method

```
if (strpos($headers[$index], 'Location: ') === 0) {
        $redirection = $headers[$index];
        break;
    }
header($redirection);
exit;
```

Have tried the following

```
header($redirection);
echo "<HTML></HTML>";
exit;
```

this below method breaks it

```
if ($headers[$index]){
        $redirection = $headers[$index];
        break;
}
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$redirection.'">';
exit;
```

---

Redirect is `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVB1r4D8QH0?version=3`

Comment: Have you looked at the server's log files to see if something is not working correctly?

Comment: Also, is using `https://` on the redirection URL required? If you remove the `s`, does that resolve the problem?

Comment: Error logs are clean, and the https:// is needed in this situation.

Comment: Yes, but, if you remove the `s`, do you still have the problem? If you do, that could be a clue. Also, I am assuming Apache is the server?

Comment: Problem still occurs when remove the `s`. Yes apache is the server

Comment: What if you just do `header("Location: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVB1r4D8QH0?version=3"); exit;` right near the beginning of the script? Might as well at least rule that possibility out.

Comment: I setup a new page to test the head redirect. Appears that's working fine, so must mean the curl in the page is taking longer in this case.

Comment: You may want to do some [profiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133686/profiling-php-code) to find out where any bottlenecks are. Or simply echo the `microtime` at various stages throughout your script.

Comment: Have you looked at it with Wireshark, to analyze the traffic? It's definitely happening on your server. When I run a filter against `ip.dst == 103.1.186.71 or ip.src == 103.1.186.71` and monitor those packets, all of the wait is during the period between send and receive. There is an error in the response, `Content-encoded entity body (gzip): 20 bytes [Error: Decompression failed]`, but that appears to be a bug in Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

try adding a output buffer at the top, dont echo anything else after it then just exit

ob_start();