# Long processing time on menu script

Tags: php, magento

I am building out a nested menu for a Magento store I am working on. The store has around 700 categories in total (that are nested around 4 levels at most) that need to be spat out into this menu.

The code I have written takes on average 2.5s to process (tested using microtime).

I am wondering if this is unavoidable given the amount of categories that need to be processed.

Anyways, this is the code I have come up with (go easy I am a front end dev by trade): NOTE: is am also using this code to loop out CMS pages in the same fashion

```
$type = Mage::registry('current_category') ? 'category' : 'page';

if($type == 'category') {
    $currentID = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
    $parentIDs = explode('/', Mage::registry('current_category')->path);
    $rootID = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
} 
else {
    $currentID = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getId();
    $parentIDs = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getPathIds();
    $rootID = 0;
}

function checkChildHtml($parentId, $htmlString) {
    $string = '';
    if($parentId != $rootID) {
        $string = $htmlString;
    }
    return $string;
}

// Recurse the site tree and build out a menu
function buildChildMenu($type, $currentID, $parentId, $isChild, $parentIDs, $rootID) {

    // Get the appropriate collection based on type
    if($type == 'category') {
        $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', '1')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', '1')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => $parentId))
            ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');
    } 
    else {
        $children = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', '1')
            ->addFieldToFilter('include_in_menu', '1')
            ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => $parentId))
            ->setOrder('position','asc');
    }

    // TODO check for $parentID != $rootID is a little hacky, need to DRY this up
    $html .= ($parentId != $rootID) ? '<ul>' : null;

    // Loop over categories at the current level
    foreach($children as $child) {

        $childId = $child->getId();
        $parent = (count($child->getChildren()) > 0) ? $child->getChildren() : false;
        $classes = [];

        // Build out class lists
        if($parent) {
            $classes[] = 'parent';
        }
        if(in_array($childId, $parentIDs, true) || count($children) == 1) {
            $classes[] = "current active";
        }
        if($childId == $currentID) {
            $classes[] = "current-page";
        }

        // Build out the list item with the values appropriate to the type
        if($type == 'category') {
            $html .= checkChildHtml($parentId, '<li class="' . implode(' ', $classes) . '">' . ($parent ? '<button class="toggle"></button>' : null) . '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '">' . $child->getName() . '</a>');
        } 
        else {
            $html .= checkChildHtml($parentId, '<li class="' . implode(' ', $classes) . '">' . ($parent ? '<button class="toggle"></button>' : null) . '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '">' . $child->title . '</a>');
        }

        // Append the list html (if not root page)
        if($parent) {
            // Get the categories below this page
            $html .= buildChildMenu($type, $currentID, $child->getId(), true, $parentIDs, $rootID);
        }

        // Close the list (if not root product page)
        $html .= checkChildHtml($parentId, '</li>');
    }

    $html .= checkChildHtml($parentId, '</ul>');

    return $html;
}

// Build out menu from root level down
$categoryListHtml = buildChildMenu($type, $currentID, $rootID, false, $parentIDs, $rootID);
```

Are there any obvious bottlenecks here? If not, what is best practise in this scenario?

For instance, should I AJAX the children when requested? Or maybe cache the menu? Or... something else?

Comment: how about you [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133686/profiling-php-code) it and let the runtime tell you where its slow?

Comment: Good call. I have not done any profiling in the past, will give that a whirl.

Comment: Any reason you can’t use `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::renderCategoriesMenuHtml()`, which is Magento’s built-in method for displaying category navigation?

Comment: Damn! That would have been a good starting point :) i can't use this built however as I have a requirement for the menu items need to be collapsable / expandable and as such, will I need to get all of the categories not just the current active ones. I also need to loop out nested CMS pages, this is not supported by the built in menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the issue was that I had my cache turned off whilst I was developing this menu. With the cache enabled the processing time is insignificant.