# Why does this code take a long time to execute?

Tags: php, yii

I would appreciate some guidance on the following issue. I am by no means an expert in php. The code below takes almost 10 seconds to execute! Is there anything I am doing that is wrong or bad practice?

```
    $data = [];
    $today = date("Y/m/d");
    $ThisYear = Date('Y'); //get current Year
    $ThisMonth = Date('m'); //get current month
    $Tday = '01'; //first day of month
    $Tmonth = '09'; //September
    if (8 < $ThisMonth && $ThisMonth < 13) {
    $AcYear = $ThisYear; }
    else {
    $AcYear = $ThisYear - 1; // sets start of academic year to be last year
    }
    $AcFullYear = $AcYear.'/'.$Tmonth.'/'.$Tday;

    //find rank in all school
    $students_rank = [];
    $school_id = Student::model()->findByAttributes(['user_master_id' => Yii::app()->user->id])->school_master_id;
    $criteria1 = new CDbCriteria;
         $criteria1->with = array('user');
        $criteria1->condition = "t.school_master_id=:school_master AND user.status ='1'";
        $criteria1->params = array(':school_master' => $school_id);
    $school_students_details = Student::model()->findAll($criteria1);
    foreach ($school_students_details as $key => $value) {
        $student_name = StudentDetails::model()->findByAttributes(['user_master_id' => $value->user_master_id]); //student details with year group
        $criteria2 = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria2->with = array('homeworkMaster');
        $criteria2->condition = "t.student_id=:student_id AND homeworkMaster.question_type_id<>:question_type_id";
        $criteria2->params = array(':student_id' => $value->user_master_id, ':question_type_id' => 6);
        $HW_assignment_track = HomeworkAssignmentTrack::model()->findAll($criteria2);
        $total_HW = count((array)$HW_assignment_track); 
        $student_score = 0;
        $student_rank = 0;

            $student_total_score = 0;
            $total_HW_marks = 0;
            $under_deadline_HW = 0;

    $criteria3 = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria3->condition = "student_id =:student_id AND status=:status AND created_at >= '$AcFullYear' AND created_at <= '$today'";
    $criteria3->params = [':student_id' => $value->user_master_id, ':status' => 2];
    $student_completed_HW = HomeworkStudentAnswere::model()->findAll($criteria3);

            $i = 1;
             foreach ($student_completed_HW as $s_c_h_K => $s_c_h_V) {
                if ($s_c_h_V->homework->homework_type == 2) {
                    $total_HW -= 1;

                } elseif ($s_c_h_V->homework->homework_type == 1) {
                    $HW_questions = HomeworkQuestion::model()->findAllByAttributes(['homework_master_id' => $s_c_h_V->homework_id, 'status' => 1]);

                    foreach ($HW_questions as $qKey => $qVal) {
                        if ($qVal->question_type_id ==3) {
                            $total_HW_marks += 2;
                        } else {
                        $total_HW_marks += $qVal->marks;

                        }
                    }
                   $assignment = HomeworkAssignmentTrack::model()->findByAttributes(['id' => $s_c_h_V->assignment_track_id]);
                    $homeworks_within_validate = Assignment::model()->findByPk($assignment->assignment_id);
                    if ($homeworks_within_validate->valid_date === '0' && $homeworks_within_validate->deadline >= date('Y-m-d')) {
                        $total_HW -= 1;
                    }
                    if ($homeworks_within_validate->valid_date === '1' || (($homeworks_within_validate->valid_date === '0') && ($homeworks_within_validate->deadline >= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($s_c_h_V->created_at))) && ($homeworks_within_validate->deadline < date('Y-m-d')))) {
                        if ($s_c_h_V->review_status === '2') {
                            $student_total_score += $s_c_h_V->score;
                        }
                    }

                    $homework_submit = HomeworkCompleteNotification::model()->findByAttributes(['homework_id' => $s_c_h_V->homework_id, 'assignment_track_id' => $s_c_h_V->assignment_track_id, 'student_id' => $value->user_master_id]);
                    if (($homeworks_within_validate->valid_date === '0') && ($homeworks_within_validate->deadline >= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($homework_submit->created_at))) && ($s_c_h_V->review_status === '2')) {
                        $under_deadline_HW += 10;
                    }
                if ($total_HW_marks !=0) {
                    $student_score += round(($student_total_score / $total_HW_marks) * 100);
                } else {
                    $student_score = 0;
                }
                }
                $i += 1;
            }

        //add revision scores to rank score
    $criteria4 = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria4->condition = "user_id =:user_id AND date_created >= '$AcFullYear' AND date_created <= '$today'";
    $criteria4->params = [':user_id' => $value->user_master_id];
    $revision_score = RevisionScores::model()->findAll($criteria4);

        $sum = 0;

            foreach($revision_score as $item) {
                $sum += $item['score'];
            } //end of adding revision scores


        $students_rank[$key]['student_id'] = $value->user_master_id;
        $students_rank[$key]['year_group'] = $student_name->year_group_id; //added year group to model array
        if ($student_score > 0) {
            $student_rank += round($student_score / $total_HW, 0) + $under_deadline_HW;
            $students_rank[$key]['rank'] = $student_rank + $sum;
        } else {
            $students_rank[$key]['rank'] = $sum;
        }
   }
    $model = $this->multid_sort($students_rank, 'rank');
    $rank_score = round(array_column($model, 'rank', 'student_id')[Yii::app()->user->id],0);

    $year_rank =[];
    $current_st = StudentDetails::model()->findByAttributes(['user_master_id' => Yii::app()->user->id]);
    $current_st_year = $current_st->year_group_id;


    $rank_list = [];
    foreach ($model as $key => $value) {
        $rank_list[] = $value['student_id'];
        if ($value['year_group'] == $current_st_year) {
        $year_rank[] = $value['student_id'];

        }
    }
    $user = Yii::app()->user->id;
    $sch_position = array_search($user,$rank_list);
    $yr_position = array_search($user,$year_rank);
    $final_rank = $sch_position + 1;
    $yr_rank = $yr_position + 1;
    $sch_rank = $final_rank;

    $ends = array('th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th');
    if (($sch_rank %100) >= 11 && ($sch_rank%100) <= 13) {
       $sc_abbreviation = 'th';
       $yr_abbreviation = 'th';
    } else {
       $sc_abbreviation = $ends[$sch_rank % 10];
       $yr_abbreviation = $ends[$yr_rank % 10];
    }

    $models = UserMaster::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
    $year_name = $models->studentDetails->yearGroup->name;

    $data['type'] = 'success';
    $data['score'] = '<div>Ranking Score: '.$rank_score.'</div>';
    $data['yr_rank'] = '<div><i class="fa fa-trophy rank-i"></i><span class="rank-number">' .$yr_rank. '</span><sup class="script-top" id="year_rank_abb">' .$yr_abbreviation. '</sup></div><div id="year_name">In ' .$year_name. '</div>';
    $data['school_rank'] = '<div><i class="fa fa-trophy rank-i"></i><span class="rank-number">' .$sch_rank. '</span><sup class="script-top" id="year_rank_abb">' .$sc_abbreviation. '</sup></div><div id="year_name">In School</div>';
    $data['rank_revise'] ='<div>'.$rank_score.'</div>';
    $data['yr_rank_revise'] = '<span>'.$yr_rank.'</span><sup class="superscript" style="left:0">'.$yr_abbreviation.'</sup>';
    $data['sch_rank_revise'] = '<span>'.$sch_rank.'</span><sup class="superscript" style="left:0">'.$sc_abbreviation.'</sup>';

    $_SESSION['rank'] = $rank_score;
    $_SESSION['accuracy'] = $rank_score;

    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
```

The above is used in an Yii application. It runs perfectly fine on localhost, but on live site, takes over 10 seconds to execute.
Your help and guidance is appreciated.

Thank

Comment: Log the time throughout the execution and see where it hangs. Perhaps your DB is located far from you? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Comment: You are doing a select query for each ID what is bad for a collection. You should first do a select query of all the data you need and **then** iterate through the results. There is a ton of query inside query. 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Profiling PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133686/profiling-php-code)

Comment: If you don't use some functions from models (as far as I can tell you are not using in this code) then there is no need to use models to fetch data from DB. Using models, in this case, would slow down and eat unnecessary memory. If you are just using DB columns values than it is much better to use DAO to access data. Also, you should rewrite this to optimize the way how you fetch data from DB, to make fewer queries that you do in this case like @MarkusZeller has suggested.

Comment: Do you have the sama in your local db as in the prod db? Usually the local db is almost empty so it makes it a lot faster. But queries on prod db takes much longer because you have a lot of data. You should verify your queries. `EXPLAIN` will help :)

Comment: Enable the Yii DB profile => https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/235/configuring-cweblogroute-for-db-profiling